# Detect redirection of remote url with php

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have a php page where it loads some predefined options and text boxes with html codes.
Later it posts data on a remote page.

```
<img src="data:<?php echo $captchaQuery['content_type'] ?>;base64,<?php echo $captcha ?>" alt="Captcha" height="30" align="absbottom" id="msg_captcha" name="msg_captcha">
<input type="text" name="f_captcha" size="8" maxlength="5">
<input type="submit" value="SEND" class="btnorange">
```

Everything works fine most of the time including remote captcha verification. When I press send button the page submits to remote url and reloads the php page.

My question is, 'when user puts wrong data in the text box the remote site redirects to another page, how can i also grab that redirected link and redirect user to that page rather than reloading my php?

Target url for for submitting data  is : $baseurl . ?psean=.

if there is an error ridirects to : $baseurl . ?psean= captcha was wrong

Comment: Is the redirect for incorrect input under your control ? If so, you need to catch the event at that page.

Comment: No the redirection is on remote site. The site decides whats correct or incorrect.

Comment: Yes, but where does it send the user if the info is wrong ? Back to your site, right ? Because if that isn't the case, then there isn't much you can do. Except, try and Ajax submit and catch the response... But that would be complicated due to a cross domain submit..

Comment: the remote site actually rejects and redirect to same page with error msg on url itself.

Comment: Could you please edit the original question with an example url that your form is at, and the url that you get returned to ?

Comment: I have edited with sample url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if the server sends redirect location in response headers

```
$url = "http://www.fb.com";
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
if(!empty($headers['Location'])) {
  $location = (array) $headers['Location'];
  header('Location:' . end($location));
}
```

Comment: Small error: `current()` expects an array. `$headers` is, but `$headers['Location']` is not.